# LESS @import does not seem to work

Tags: css, linux, ubuntu, less

Using the command line program `lessc` [installed by following this guide](http://ken.edmonds-commerce.co.uk/others/css/four-commands-away-from-installing-less-css-on-ubuntu/) on a Ubuntu machine, don't seem to compile `@import` rules as I expected.

```
$ echo '@import "inc.less"' > test.less
$ echo 'body { background: pink }' > inc.less
$ lessc test.less
```

The output is an empty line. I expected the contents of inc.less. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `@import "inc";`

Don't use the `.less` extension. I also think you need a semicolon.

For example, here's a couple of lines that are working for me:

```
@import "blueprint/screen";
@import "blueprint/ie";

a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FF0000;
}
```

That imports *blueprint/screen.less* and *blueprint/ie.less* into the file.